# Enabling PDO_OCI in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have been using `oci_` in PHP but I would like to start using PDO.

I have read http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php but I'm not sure how to enable PDO_OCI. I see the command listed on the page but I installed PHP using `sudo apt-get install php5` and not via the source.

```
<?php
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
?>
```

shows

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
)
```

Can someone help as the PHP website does not have much information other than that single command? I understand it is experimental but I would like to try it, I just can't find much information on it.

Comment: did you follow the instructions on [PDO Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php)?

Comment: @EvilEpidemic Where do I get the .so for PDO_OCI?

Answer (score 0):

Install the PDO_OCI drivers using pecl.  This tutorial may help: [Installing PHP & Oracle PDO Drivers on Ubuntu](http://bencornwell.com/112/)